# Python 3.3 Console NameError

Tags: python-3.x

I'm getting a weird error occurring. I'm trying to run a text based game through the python console window, the code runs very well in **IDLE** but when I run in **console** it executes the step to ask for a name then immediately closes.

The error code is"
`NameError: name 'JJ' is not defined`

The code its supposedly executing is:

```
print ("*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*")
print ("*|Welcome to the Game|*")
print ("*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*")
print ("")
time.sleep(1)
User_name = input ("What is your Name? ")
time.sleep(1)
print ("Welcome",User_name," enter irrelevant story information here")
print("more irrelevant story here.")
print ("more irrelevant story here")
print ("")
time.sleep (1)
```

I have verified several times that I'm running python 3.3 and the console says" C:\Python33\py.exe so I believe that's also in accordance.

and Yes I did import the time library, that is definitely not the error.

many thanks ahead of time for any help!

Edit: to clear up confusion: Here is a link to pictures showing what is going on: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNest.jpg

the first picture shows the error, the second picture shows the code and the third picture shows the program running in IDLE without an error.

Comment: As long as I import the time module, it works fine for me.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `input` with `raw_input` just to see? Because it really does look like you're running Python 2 instead of 3.

Comment: @Cairnarvon, I think you just nailed it.  I ran the program under Python 2.x, entered "JJ" for the name, and got the exact error described above.  I'm adding a suggestion to the end of my answer.

Comment: I did try replacing input with raw_input as I saw suggested on other posts, however at that point I got an error saying that raw_input was not defined. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are running Python 3 in IDLE and Python 2 at the console.  Run python with no parameters at the console and watch the sign-on text.  You mentioned running `py.exe`.  `py.exe` is a launcher that manages running multiple versions of Python on a single system.  To ensure you are running the version of Python you want, add the following as the first line of the script:

```
#!python3
```

Alternatively, run `py.exe -3` to force use of Python 3.

The clues are `input` in Python 2 executes its input as code, which is why entering `JJ` gives the error you see.  `raw_input` does not.  `raw_input` is not available in Python 3, and `input` in Python 3 works like `raw_input` in Python 2.

Examples:

```
C:\>py -2
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> raw_input('?')
?JJ
'JJ'
>>> input('?')
?JJ
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'JJ' is not defined
>>> ^Z

C:\>py -3
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> raw_input()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
>>> input()
JJ
'JJ'
>>>
```

Comment: Thats done it, I'm not sure how it was running anything other than 3.3 since I check to make sure my shortcut is for python 3.3 but using the #!python3 solved it nicely. Thank you!

Comment: `py.exe` is not the Python 3.3 interpreter, even if it is in the Python 3.3 directory (it isn't installed there by default, so not sure why you have it there).  `python.exe` is the Python interpreter.  `py.exe` is a launcher (first available with Python 3.3) that can select the version of Python to run by examining the `#!` comment at the start of the script.  See [Python Launcher for Windows](http://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?highlight=launcher#python-launcher-for-windows).

Comment: thats weird that it isn't even installed in the same directory, I didn't change anything from the stock install. you solution fixed the issue though so I'm not too concerned with it. Thank you very much, again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks okay as far as I can see.  And, I ran it and it worked fine for me.  So, it seems you aren't running exactly the code you showed us here; maybe there is more code, or maybe you made a mistake when you tried to run it.

I suggest you place the program in a source file, rather than pasting it in to a console.  Then when you get the error, the stack backtrace will show you the exact spot in your program where Python had the problem.

Then work backward and figure out what caused the problem, and fix it.

For example, I made a source file with the exact text of the program you provided, and tried to run it.  Since I never imported `time`, I knew it would fail.  Here is the backtrace I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

The solution to this one is to `import time` on a line before line 5.

EDIT: I think @Cairnarvon has suggested the correct answer.  I think this program is being run under Python 2.x.  @Cairnarvon suggested you change your program to use `raw_input()` as a check; if you really are running under Python 2.x your program will suddenly work, and if you are running under Python 3.x you will get a `NameError` on the `raw_input` line.

One other way to check it is to add this code:

```
import sys
assert sys.version_info[0] >= 3
```

The good thing about this check is that you can leave it in, and it will tell you clearly the problem if the problem happens again.

EDIT: Also, you can add this at the top of your program:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Then make sure it prints a version number starting with 3.  If you do get a version number starting with 3, please paste it in the question; someone might spot a clue in the version info.

Comment: I believe there is a misunderstanding here, the code runs in IDLE without a problem. but when I just click on the icon of the saved file then I get this error: http://imgur.com/izsys7h  Here is a screen capture of my current code:http://imgur.com/GzZMEOh you can see that I have imported time, that is not the problem since the code has run in IDLE every time I've tried, just it has not run in the console window. Thanks though